# Cropping and resizing images in laravel

Tags: php, image, upload, crop

I want to crop/resize an image in Laravel (4.2). But it doen't seem to work very well...

So I Want to be able to upload an image, but resize it to a maximum width and height.

How should I do this?

The code I have now is:

```
//save the image
            $destinationPath = 'public/pictures/news';

            if (Input::hasFile('img'))
            {
                $file = Input::file('img');
                $file->move('public/pictures/news', $file->getClientOriginalName());
            }
```

So, I want a code in the `if()` statement, that crops the image. to a specified max-width and max-height.

If someone could help me out, I would be very happy!

Kindes regards,

Robin

Comment: this will make your life lot easier http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation

Comment: Yeah, that, doesn't work. And I want them to be cropped BEFORE they are uploaded and not cropped in an img tag.

Answer (score 0):

use image intervention package it is providing an easier and expressive way to create, edit, and compose images.

https://packagist.org/packages/intervention/image